# How to correctly use gsub to replace string

Tags: r, regex

I looked at some of the other answers and tried to copy the code, but no luck, yet. I have a list of street names and want to keep the names, but take out their designation as street, st, stret, avenue, avnuen, etc. Obviously, some are spelled incorrectly. I have tried the following:

```
group<-c("avenue", "avenuen", "ave", "street", "st", "stret")
group
result: "avenue" "avenue" "ave" "street" "st" "stret"
gsub("avenue","avenue","ave","street","st","stret","",group)
result[1] ""
```

However, when I look at the table with my data, none of these words are gone.

I tried it with one string as well:

```
group <- "avenue"
gsub("avenue", "", group)
result[1]""
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your patience with a very new R-user.

Comment: group <- c("avenue", "aveune", "ave", "street", "st", "stret")                            group                                                                                                              result: "avenue" "aveune" "ave" "street" "st" "stret"                                         gsub("avenue", "aveune" ,"ave", "street","st","stret", "", group)               group                                                                                                          result: [1]""          nothing changes in my table though. all words remain

Comment: What is the sample string and expected output? Are you looking for [something like this](https://ideone.com/7Kj4KI.)?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/7Kj4KI.

Answer (score 0):

In your gsub command replace all of your commas with an "|" operator and put all your strings in one set of quotation marks. So something like gsub("avenue|ave|aven", "", group).